# ASP.net Core MailKit SmtpClient saying "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, asp.net-core, mailkit

I am working with ASP.net Core and trying to setup a simple smtp email feature.  I am using the MailKit nuget package.  Here is my code:

```
public void SendEmail(List<string> emails, string body, string subject)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
    
        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", "test@gmail.com"));
        foreach(var e in emails)
        {
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", e));
        }
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
    
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            client.Authenticate("username", "password");
            client.Send(emailMessage);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

    }
```

I'm getting an exception at the client.Connect() method saying:
"Specified cast is not valid".

The documentation for the Connect() method is [here](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_Connect_1.htm).  It shows the prototype for the method is (string host, int port, SecureSocketOptions options) which I have so I'm not sure why it's giving me a casting exception...

I've also tried using port 465 with the SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect but still got the same exception.  Can anybody help with this?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**
As requested, here is the stack trace from the exception:

"   at <>x.<>m0(CustomerService <>4__this, List`1 emails, String body, String subject)"

Unfortunately it's not much to go on.  CustomerService is the class that my email method is in.

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: What about 587 without StartTLS?

Comment: @jstedfast, I tried with 587 and no SecureSocketOptions and got the same exception and stack trace.  client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

Comment: Based on your StackTrace, the exception isn't coming from MailKit, it's coming from *your* code.

Comment: `client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);` uses StartTLS. You need to pass `SecureSocketOptions.None`.

Comment: @jstedfast I've attempted to use SecureSocketOptions.None and it gets through the .Connect() call, however throws an exception at the .Authenticate() method: "The SMTP server does not support authentication."  So if I remove the .Authenticate method, when I get to .Send(), I get the exception "5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p7sm3792855itg.14 - gsmtp".  Doesn't really make sense to remove .Authenticate though since it's the only way to connect to my gmail account (that I know of).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machine so I'll need you to compile MailKit from source and step through it with a debugger and tell me exactly where this CastException is coming from.

Comment: @jstedfast I'm working on getting MailKit source included now.  You'll have to excuse my inexperience in this matter as I've never done this before, so it's taking me a while to figure out how to get it compiled and debuggable from my project.  If you have any tips on a quick/easy way to do this, I'm all ears!

Comment: You don't need to debug YOUR project, you just need to debug A project. That is trick #1 all developers need to know.

Comment: Just create a simple ASP.NET Core project that references the MimeKit .NET Core  and MailKit .NET Core projects.

Comment: @jstedfast So I was developing on a Mac using VS Code when I was experiencing these errors.  When I switched my app over to windows and ran it through visual studio, it worked without any problems using ports 465 and 587 with the SecureSocketOptions.  My concern is that MailKit may not be cross platform compatible.  Have you tested on OSX/Linux?  I will try to do some further investigation.